# How can I evaluate safely a boolean expression represented as a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, database, parsing, vue.js, eval

I  have a questionnaire, I want the questions to show or hide dynamically based on a rule represented as a string (e.g. `answers[1] == 'yes' || (answers[2] > 18 && answers[2] < 24)`).

These rules come directly from the database and always evaluate to true or false. If it's true the question is shown and if it's false the question remains hidden. For the front-end I'm using vue.js, these rules are passed as a prop and should be evaluated at runtime within a component.

What would be the best way to do this?

- For testing purposes I've tried `eval()` and it just works. But I know it's not a safe option so I'm looking for alternatives.
- An alternative I've considered was replacing the appearances of "answers[x]" with their values since I know that's the only variable I have to access. But in the end this would output to another string that has to be evaluated.
- I've seen that there's a package called [safe-eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-eval) that would sandbox an eval function and I could pass a context so the answers are available. I've seen that it had a pretty big security hole in the past version but should be fixed. Would this be a good alternative?
- Is there some kind of library that could help me write a parser, or that offers a way to write rules and evaluate them?

Edit: The reason why I considered `safe-eval` firstly, instead of a custom parser, is because I can evaluate complex logic without getting into writing a huge class to tackle all this logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider writing a parser to convert rules from the database into JavaScript functions. Most of the details depends on the structure of the rules you need to handle, but a quick example in pseudo-code could be:

```
function parse(string) {
    if (string.match("answers[:d] > :d", question_number, threshold)) {
        return function (answers) {
            return answers[question_number] > threshold;
        };
    }
}
...
answers = [...];
var rule = parse("answers[1] > 18");
if (rule(answers)) {
    // answer[1] > 18
}
else {
    // answer[1] <= 18
}
```

This would be even safer than save-eval.

Comment: That one string was just as an example. The idea would be to evaluate complex boolean rules, or at least more complex than that. Specially taking into account multiple answers. For example:

answers[1] == 'yes' || (answers[2] > 18 && answers[2] < 24)

I know that a custom parser would be ideal, but it seems a bit too complex to parse this kind of logic efficiently and I want to avoid getting into that, specially if there's a better and more simple alternative to achieve it.

Comment: If a custom parser is not an option, then eval and alike is the way to go. As long as you can guarantee that strings in your database are safe, you should not encounter problems with eval or safe-eval.

Comment: I was looking now for some kind of library that could make the process easier. I'm not mainly a front-end dev and wouldn't like to screw things up writing a parser like that in javascript. I'm afraid it would end up being too slow.

Comment: In the end writing a parser was the way I went and worked out pretty well. It also allowed me to make an abstraction on the boolean syntax used across the database

Comment: I'm glad to know that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a regular expression to ensure that the string fits your format, and only run `eval()` if it matches the regex. If you need a reference for creating a regex, I recommend https://regex101.com/

```js
var rule = 'answers[1] > 18';
var regex = /^answers\[\d+\]\s>\s\d+$/;
var answers = [8, 27, 64];

if (rule.match(regex))
  console.log(eval(rule));
```

Comment: I've considered a regular expression check too, but for complex expressions like `answers[1] == 'yes' || (answers[2] > 18 && answers[2] < 24)` I'm not sure if some malicious code might slip through.

Comment: You could still use a regular expression, but to ensure it would match your complex rules, it would become equally complex with all the optional characters/groupings. If you are worried that a good regex would be too difficult to write/maintain, then I'd recommend `safe-eval`